# App crashes whenever I press login. Need help in Debugging

Tags: android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

I am building a dating app. I coded the part where a swipe of left or right would register it in the Firebase Database. App runs and everything but now when I try to login from the login page the app crashes. The only thing that I changed prior to the crashes was in the MainActivty so therefore I am including that. Since i am new to this i dont really know how to fix this.

***The following is the MainActivity.java***

```
package com.example.macdate;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.lorentzos.flingswipe.SwipeFlingAdapterView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private cards cards_data[];
    private ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;
    private int i;

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private String currentUId;
    private DatabaseReference usersDb;



    ListView listView;
    List<cards> rowItems;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        usersDb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
        mAuth   = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        checkUserSex();
        rowItems = new ArrayList<cards>();

        arrayAdapter = new arrayAdapter(this, R.layout.item, rowItems);

        SwipeFlingAdapterView flingContainer = (SwipeFlingAdapterView) findViewById(R.id.frame);

        flingContainer.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        flingContainer.setFlingListener(new SwipeFlingAdapterView.onFlingListener() {
            @Override
            public void removeFirstObjectInAdapter() {
                // this is the simplest way to delete an object from the Adapter (/AdapterView)
                Log.d("LIST", "removed object!");
                rowItems.remove(0); // Every time the swipe is done completely the card is removed
                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onLeftCardExit(Object dataObject) {
                //Do something on the left!
                //You also have access to the original object.
                //If you want to use it just cast it (String) dataObject
                cards obj = (cards) dataObject;
                String userId = obj.getUserId();
                usersDb.child(oppositeUserSex).child(userId).child("connections").child("nope").child(currentUId).setValue(true); //registering the swipes to the database
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onRightCardExit(Object dataObject) {
                cards obj = (cards) dataObject;
                String userId = obj.getUserId();
                usersDb.child(oppositeUserSex).child(userId).child("connections").child("yeps").child(currentUId).setValue(true);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();            }

            @Override
            public void onAdapterAboutToEmpty(int itemsInAdapter) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(float scrollProgressPercent) {

            }
        });


        // Optionally add an OnItemClickListener
        flingContainer.setOnItemClickListener(new SwipeFlingAdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClicked(int itemPosition, Object dataObject) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();            }
        });

    }
    private String userSex;
    private String oppositeUserSex;
    public void checkUserSex(){
        final FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        DatabaseReference maleDb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("Male");
        maleDb.addChildEventListener((new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                if(dataSnapshot.getKey().equals(user.getUid())){
                    userSex = "Male";
                    oppositeUserSex = "Female";
                    getOppositeSexUsers();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        }));

        DatabaseReference femaleDb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("Female");
        femaleDb.addChildEventListener((new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                if(dataSnapshot.getKey().equals(user.getUid())){
                    userSex = "Female";
                    oppositeUserSex = "Male";
                    getOppositeSexUsers();

                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        }));
    }

    public void getOppositeSexUsers(){
        DatabaseReference oppositeSexDb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(oppositeUserSex);
        oppositeSexDb.addChildEventListener((new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                if(dataSnapshot.exists() && !dataSnapshot.child("connections").child("nope").hasChild(currentUId) && !dataSnapshot.child("connections").child("yeps").hasChild(currentUId)){

                    cards item = new cards(dataSnapshot.getKey(),dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString());
                    rowItems.add(item);
                    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        }));


    }


    public void logoutUser(View view){
        mAuth.signOut();
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ChooseLoginRegistrationActivity.class); //takes out to the choose page
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
        return;


    }



}
```

***The following is the Logcat***

```
2020-04-11 00:23:27.262 12387-12431/com.example.macdate D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xaf6b2ca0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xa5f308f0)
2020-04-11 00:23:27.301 12387-12488/com.example.macdate D/FA: Connected to remote service
2020-04-11 00:23:27.303 12387-12488/com.example.macdate V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 4
2020-04-11 00:23:27.684 12387-12387/com.example.macdate D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2020-04-11 00:23:27.685 12387-12387/com.example.macdate E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.macdate, PID: 12387
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.lang.CharSequence.length()' on a null object reference
        at java.util.regex.Matcher.reset(Matcher.java:1052)
        at java.util.regex.Matcher.<init>(Matcher.java:180)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern.matcher(Pattern.java:1006)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.Validation.isValidPathString(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:40)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.Validation.validatePathString(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:44)
        at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.hasChild(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:80)
        at com.example.macdate.MainActivity$5.onChildAdded(MainActivity.java:165)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.ChildEventRegistration.fireEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:79)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:63)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:55)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: Sorry that reallly doesn't answer my question